# Error drawing vertical line in jqPlot where X-axis has date format

Tags: jqplot

I know there are similar questions, and they seem to have similar answers, which I have tried to no avail.

Here is my `canvasOverlay`:

```
        canvasOverlay: {
            show: true,
            objects: [
                {verticalLine: {
                    x: new $.jsDate('May 29, 2014 7:58:55').getTime(),
                    lineWidth: 5,
                    color: 'rgb(0,198,0)',
                    shadow: false
                }}]}
```

(the date range of the plot starts 10 seconds before this time and ends 50 after).

And here is the error I get:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'ah._ctx')
    aa (jquery.jqplot.min.js, line 3)
    h (jquery.jqplot.min.js, line 3)
    dispatch (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    handle (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    trigger (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    (anonymous function) (jquery.min.js, line 3)
    each (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    each (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    trigger (jquery.min.js, line 3)
    onMouseMove (jquery.jqplot.min.js, line 3)
    dispatch (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    handle (jquery.min.js, line 2)
```

I notice that the `canvasOverly` plugin does not show up in the trace, which seems odd.  I am including it the body, and the browser debugger (Safari) does report it having been loaded.  If I comment out the canvasOverlay element, the error does not show up.  Either way, the hoped-for vertical line does not appear.

The rest of the plot spec isn't particularly remarkable:

```
        dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
        dataRendererOptions: {
          unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            lineWidth: 1.0,
            showMarker: false,
            yaxis: 'y2axis',
            showLabel: true
        },
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions: { showLabel: true }
            },
            y2axis:{
                tickOptions: { formatString: "%7d" }
            }
        },
        legend: { show: true },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` as set in the definition of `canvasOverlay` would have worked; however, elsewhere in the code, it was being overwritten with a date still in text form.